# Python Regular Expression for removing internal spaces but not \n and \t

Tags: python, regex

I am displaying some text on a Python dialog which is received in the following format

```
"   Some text\n\n    With internal padding   "
```

The internal padding is outside of my control. I want to retain the \n (and also any tab characters, if present) but remove the literal internal spaces following the newline characters.

The **desired** resulting string would be

```
"Some text\n\nWith internal padding".
```

So that when it is displayed, everything is nicely left-aligned.

Removing the start and end spaces is simple

`text.strip()`

To handle the internal spaces, I initially tried

`re.sub("\n\s+","\n",text)`

but this resulted in removing any multiple new-line occurences which I don't want! I think I need a regular expression which says

**"Remove all literal spaces directly following a newline character, but not otherwise"**

but I cannot figure out the re syntax for this, I tried

`re.sub("\n[\s+^\n]","\n",text)`, but this was not what I wanted.

Any help from re-ninjas appreciated.

Comment: \s = \n + \ + \t + \r. I suggest using regex groups: `[\ \t]` (check out: https://regexone.com/lesson/whitespaces)

Comment: @MisirJafarov -> so something like ```re.sub("\n[\ \t]+","\n",text)``` right? I just tried this and it seems to work. The ```[\ \t]``` is matching a space or a tab, the ```+``` says "match as many as possible" and the ```\n``` at the start says "match this stuff when it follows a newline character. Is that basically right?

Comment: I didn't get what you wanted to do, :/ check out this query: `re.sub('\ +', ' ', text)` which works for me, simply replaces multiple space characters (because you don't want new line and tabs to be removed, in that case, you only need to remove \ space) with just one space

Comment: Use `re.sub(r'(?:^|\n)[^\S\n\t]+|[^\S\n\t]+$|([^\S\n\t])+', r'\1', text.strip())` or something. It is still not clear what you want to do with tabs or newlines at the start/end of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier solution without the `re` package:

```
x = "   Some text\n\n    With internal padding   "
'\n'.join(i.strip() for i in x.split('\n'))
```

Comment: Nice. I was a bit blinded by using regex, but this is elegant.

Comment: That is very elegant indeed (y)

Comment: Much more better than regex +1

Answer (score 2):

You could use `((?<=\n)|^) +| +$|  +` This removes spaces at the end of each line and the end of the string as well. See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CgPGvY/5)

Comment: Yes, and? The lookbehind is for the `\n` not for the spaces

Answer (score 0):

```py
re.sub(r"( )+", " ", "   Some text\n\n    With internal padding   ".strip())
```

or

```py
re.sub(r"( )+", " ", text.strip())
```

Comment: This doesn't quite do what the OP asks, in that it leaves a single space following the newlines

Answer (score 0):

Looks like removing any sequence of more than 1 space or any number of trailing white spaces. So this regular expression substitution will do it.

```
import re

re.sub(" {2,}| $", "", "   Some text\n\n    With internal padding   ")
```

Output:

```
'Some text\n\nWith internal padding'
```

Comment: This will not remove a single space after linebreak: `text\n\n text` will not change.